# Ошибка при в процессе компиляция с помощью pyqtdeploy. Создаю на android приложение из pyqt5 программы

Tags: android, python, pyqt5

Код программы

```py
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl, QTimer
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView

app = QApplication([])

mw = QWebEngineView()
mw.load(QUrl("https://ru.stackoverflow.com"))
mw.setEnabled(False)
mw.show()

QTimer.singleShot(5000, lambda: mw.setEnabled(True))

app.exec()
```

Необходимо её компилировать в apk файл без преобразования в kivy и т.д. Нашёл самое как мне показалось комфортное решение - pyqtdeploy.

Создал файл testingg.pdy.

Дошёл до действия сборки, вбиваю команду

```
pyqtdeploy-build testingg.pdy
```

И в ответ получаю ошибку

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python\Python37-32\Scripts\pyqtdeploy-build-script.py", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('pyqtdeploy==2.4', 'console_scripts', 'pyqtdeploy-build')()
  File "C:\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pyqtdeploy\pyqtdeploybuild_main.py", line 93, in main
    standard_library_dir=args.standard_library_dir)
  File "C:\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pyqtdeploy\builder\builder.py", line 158, in build
    self._check_interpreter_version(interpreter, py_version)
  File "C:\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pyqtdeploy\builder\builder.py", line 1328, in _check_interpreter_version
    stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
  File "C:\Python\Python37-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 395, in check_output
    **kwargs).stdout
  File "C:\Python\Python37-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 472, in run
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
  File "C:\Python\Python37-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 775, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Python\Python37-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 1178, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] Не удается найти указанный файл
```

Уже потратил много времени на поиск решения и не нашёл ничего подходящего. Подскажите кто знает. Спасибо!

Comment: Встретился с этой проблемой, вы нашли решение?

Comment: Нет, использую pyinstaller .. проще и функционал такой же почти